# compare value of an attribute with another attribute in xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have started learning XSLT and I have a question:
I want to compare a value of an attribute of a node with a value of an attribute of an other node to show a message.

For example, we have the following XML:

```
<groupe>   
  <product id='05'>
    <item>
        <special id_product = '022'>
        </special>
    </item>
  </product>

  <product id='05'>
    <item>
        <special id_product = '022'>
        </special>
    </item>
  </product>
</groupe>
```

I want to compare between `id` and `id_product` if there are different then show a message like "there are different". thank you alot

Comment: Try using a template that matches `product[not(@id=item/special/@id_product)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a whole template the solution could look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="product" > 
    <xsl:if test="not(@id=item/special/@id_product)">
        <xsl:value-of select="'They are different!&#xa;'" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank u ! zX485 :)